# Properties of a matrix and eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A, B, C are three real-square matrices. A is an upper triangular matrix with all of its diagonal entries equal to zero. B is a matrix such that $b_{ij}=-b_{ji}$, and C is a matrix such that $\sum_j c_{ij}c_{jk} = \delta_{ik}$ in which $\delta_{ik}$ is a Kronecker delta. It's obvious that since A has determinant zero, at least one of its eigenvalue is zero, is there any more we could deduce about eigenvalues of A just from its properties? Also, for B and C, I am not quite sure what to say about their eigenvalues... Any hints or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $B$ is [skew-symmetric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skew-symmetric_matrix) and has det=0 if the dimension is odd.

Comment: The matrix $\;A\;$ is in fact nilpotent and thus zero is its *only* eigenvalue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The matrix $A$ is (strictly) upper triangle matrix so its eigenvalues are the entries on its diagonal so all the eigenvalues are $0$.
- The matrix $B$ is skew-symmetric and if $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ i.e. $B^T=-B$ and $x$ is an eigenvector associated to it then

$$\lambda ||x||^2=\langle Bx, x\rangle=\langle x, B^Tx\rangle=-\overline\lambda||x||^2$$
so we conclude that $\lambda=-\overline\lambda$ and then $\lambda$ is $0$ or pure imaginary.

- The matrix $C$ verify: $C^2=I_n$ so the polynomial $x^2-1$ annihilates $C$ and then
  $$\operatorname{sp}(C)\subset\{-1,1\}$$
  or we can found this previous result by saying that $C$ is a matrix of a symmetry.

Comment: How about $ C=-I_n $ with all eigenvalues $-1 $?

Comment: Sorry I fixed the mistake: the roots of $x^2-1$ are obviously $\pm1$.

Comment: I just found the answer (not the proof), and it says for B, all non-zero eigenvalues are pure imaginary, and for C, each real eigenvalue must be -1, not -1 or 1. For B, I probably could apply spectral theorem to find it out, but I'm not sure why for C, the real eigenvalue is -1 instead of 1 or -1 (you're right about A).

Comment: I think that the answer that you have is wrong!@user98235

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane  well, it was from UPenn prelim 
http://hans.math.upenn.edu/amcs/AMCS/prelims/prelim_review.pdf
in linear algebra section, problem 2. For c), (which corresponds to matrix A) the matching condition is (B), and for d), (which corresponds to matrix C) the matching condition is (F), and for f), (which corresponds to matrix B) the matching condition is A).

Comment: (a) with (B), (b) with (E), (c) with (B), (d) with (F), (e) with (D), (f) with (A) and notice in this last case that I proved in my answer the case of real eigenvalue i.e. if $\lambda$ is a real eigenvalue then $\lambda=0$ so let me edit my answer for the general case.@user98235

Comment: @user98235 I edited my answer.

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane  well. I'm still not sure why the real eigenvalue for C should be -1 instead of 1 or -1, but thanks for the answer. I've chosen your answer.

Comment: For $C$ the option isn't its real eigenvalue  should be $-1$ but the **negative** eigenvalue is **-1** and of course  as I explained in my answer the positive eigenvalue is $1$.@user98235

Comment: @SamiBenRomdhane I must have some serious reading problems nowadays... thanks again!